# Why is SQL query with subquery not working?

Tags: sql

I have two SQL tables: cars and lap_times.

```
cars: 
- car_id
- engine_size
- car_type

lap_times
- lap_time_id
- time
- car_id
```

i want to get the following: 
- number of cars per car_type
- average engine size per car_type
- fastest lap among all cars in each car_type

I have this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(cars.car_id), 
    AVG(cars.engine_size), 
    lps.FASTEST_LAP 
FROM 
    cars, 
    (SELECT lap_times.car_id AS C_ID, MIN(lap_times.time) AS FASTEST_LAP FROM lap_times) as lps 
WHERE 
    cars.car_id = lps.C_ID 
GROUP BY 
    cars.car_type
```

But I'm not getting anything. I don't get an error, though. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: By the way, shouldn't you use MIN(time) to determine the fastest lap? You have MAX in your subquery.

Comment: There are better ways to do this query (as per the answers), but if you need to create a derived table that's "dynamic" you can use `CROSS` and `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: All the answers are the same and they just make the AVG function include each car's engine size multiple times as each car has many lap times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind. Fixed it by grouping inside the subquery.

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(cars.car_id),  
    AVG(cars.engine_size),  
    lps.FASTEST_LAP  
FROM  
    cars,  
    (SELECT lap_times.car_id AS C_ID, MIN(lap_times.time) AS FASTEST_LAP FROM lap_times GROUP BY lap_times.car_id) as lps
WHERE  
    cars.car_id = lps.C_ID  
GROUP BY  
    cars.car_type
```

Comment: inside subquery? you meant query - i cannot see second select here

Comment: this is the subquery. i left the rest of the stuff out.

Comment: ah ok, it is not the full sql - got it - sorry :)

Comment: this doesnt group by car type

Comment: again, this is just the subquery

Comment: doesn't work
Column 'lps.FASTEST_LAP' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your subquery, you expect that subquery returns fastest car_id and returns some car_id.

I suggest to you to learn about [GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Also, in case your subquery runs as you espect, only one car will be selected but not one car by car_type.

This is homework? You should tag it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  a.Car_Type, 
        COUNT(a.car_ID) as NoOfCars,
        AVG(a.engine_size) as AverageEngine,
        MIN(b.time) as Fastest
FROM    cars a INNER JOIN lap_times b ON
            a.Car_ID = b.Car_ID
GROUP BY a.car_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
SELECT cars.car_type,
       COUNT(cars.car_id),
       AVG(cars.engine_size),
       MIN(lps.FASTEST_LAP)
  FROM cars,
       lap_times
 WHERE cars.car_id = lps.C_ID
 GROUP BY cars.car_type
```

Comment: I had already tried this and didn't work because the AVG function ended up including each car's engine size multiple times for each lap time. Thanks though. I solved the problem. Just had to group inside the derived table.

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE as(
    select car_type, count(*) as count_cars, avg(engine_size) as avg_engine
    from cars C
    group by car_type
)
select * , 
     (SELECT MIN(time) FROM lap_times where car_id in (select car_id from cars where car_type=CTE.car_type))  
from CTE
```